# XPATH search for all nodes inside several specific nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I want to take all "grand" nodes which are inside specific nodes (not all*). In the example bellow, I want all "grand" nodes which are inside "foo", "buz" and "more". Is there a possibility of searching by multiple parents. `'//{multiple parent nodes}/grand'???`

```
<doc>
    <foo>
        <grand>Hello</grand>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <grand>Hello</grand>
    </bar>
    <buz>
        <grand>Hello</grand>
    </buz>
    <other>
        <grand>Hello</grand>
    </other>
    <more>
        <grand>Hello</grand>
    </more>
</doc>
```

***The nodes I want to search are not by pattern.**

Comment: For your specific case, `//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'node')]/grand` should work (although the XML is badly formed as you have `</word>`

Comment: Form copy and pasting and editing forgot to replace "word". This is just pseudo xml. I will edit my example, because I mislead you. The names are not by pattern. Can I specified a list of names that I want to search.

Comment: Just added another duplicate for that - which would mean something like `//grand[parent::node-1|parent::node-3]`

Comment: @NigelRen Thaks